# Mac OS X Terminal: How can I make my pico editor syntax highlight?

Tags: macos, terminal, colors

I recently [changed my Mac OS X Terminal colors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9821/how-can-i-make-my-terminal-colorful-like-ubuntu-terminal).

How can I enable syntax highlighting for pico? Or any editor in general?

Comment: Not really a Mac question?

Comment: Not specifically a Mac question, no.

Comment: @VxJasonxV: My last comment was migrated from Apple.SE along with the question. Just to let you know.

Comment: I know. But good clarification for everyone else. My comment was from apple.se too!

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but I feel it could still be elaborated on a bit.

As mentioned, `pico` does not have syntax highlighting but `nano` does, as well as `vim` (although that is a significantly different editor!).

*The short version:* Add the line `include /usr/share/nano/*` to `~/.nanorc` and create the file if it doesn't exist.

*The long version:* `nano` stores its syntax highlighting in a global directory, most likely somewhere like `/usr/share/nano/` (This is the default on my `Debian` based machines). Highlighting files are split up by type, so highlighting for the 'C' language would be located in `/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc`. Highlighting can be enabled by using an `include` statement, either in the global config file `/etc/nanorc` or the user config file `~/.nanorc`. You may include each file individually by `include /usr/share/nano/c.nanorc` OR use a wildcard operator and include all files in the directory by using `include /usr/share/nano/*`

A quick note on `vi` and `vim` - many systems come with `vi` installed by default, which does NOT support syntax highlighting. If `vim` is installed, then syntax highlighting can be turned on by adding `syntax on` to either the global config file at `/etc/vim/vimrc` or the user config file `~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 1):

pico does not have syntax highlighting. Other text editors each have their own specific methods for enabling syntax highlighting.

Comment: OP may be interested in [GNU `nano`](http://www.gnu.org/software/nano/), which is very similar to pico, and supports [syntax highlighting](http://www.nano-editor.org/colorsyntax.png).

Comment: Nah. You just *know* he wants to jump into emacs face first.

Comment: Insert obligatory: "I'm sorry, I think you mean Vim."

Comment: I'm actually considering re-learning vi or pick up emacs. I'm still looking for reasons to lean towards one.

Comment: The OSX terminal has nano. How can I enable syntax highlighting for nano?

Comment: Don't re-learn vi, learn vim. It's so much better (you can have it behave just like vi if you want).

Answer (score 0):

Per [Pico's Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)), Pico did not have Syntax Highlighting, nano does. According to [nano's site](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/faq.html#3.6), it's a compile time option, and then if memory serves it will just work based off extension or file content.

Vim is generally syntax highlighted by default, but may take some special black magic in order to invoke it in case it's not. (`set nocompatible`, launch via `vim` instead of `vi`, `syntax on` and `set syntax=$lang`, etc.)

Most X/Visual text editors will automatically syntax highlight.

Any specific ones you're also interested in?